# How to change color for negative value on Excel vertical axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a chart that has both positive and negative values. I would like to conditionally format the color of the negative value titles on the vertical axis.
Is this possible to do in the Excel line charts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that by "value titles on the vertical axis", you mean the tick labels (numbers) on the Y axis, then the answer is "Yes". You can set the "Number format" of the chart's Y axis to use colours for negative numbers. The following instructions are for Excel 2016. The method may be slightly different for other versions.

- Right-click on the chart's Y axis.
- Choose "Format Axis ..." from the context menu.
- In the "Number" section, select the "Custom" category.
- Set the Format Code for to include colours for negative (and/or positive) numbers as you would for any cell.
- Click "add".

Here is an example that show negative numbers in red.

[image]
[image]